# Wrong day of week from date picker

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using following code to get date. Also I want to know which day of week it is. 
I am getting it,but its displaying wrong week name. For eg Today is Thursday bt its giving Sunday.

I saw many questions related to same problem but couldn't get the solution. 
Please help. 
Here is my code. I tried with both m1+1 and m1,but didn't wrk.

```
y1 = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        m1 = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        d1 = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        h1 = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        min1 = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    dayOfWeek=DateFormat.format("EEEE", new Date(y1, (m1+1), d1)).toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have calender instance, then you should you

```
android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE", calendar);
// or
android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE", calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

---

So Use

```
dayOfWeek=DateFormat.format("EEEE", calendar).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. even date() method is deprecated. 
Thanks again.